# How do I put numbers with different roundings in a matrix?

Tags: r

I'm trying to place numbers in the same column of a matrix with different roundings. However, whenever I try, the numbers with the less precise roundings have a bunch of zeroes tacked on. How do I fix this?

```
> b <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol = 2)
> b[1,1] <- 20
> b[2,1] <- 4.42
> b
      [,1] [,2]
[1,] 20.00   NA
[2,]  4.42   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are combining a bunch of `integers` with a bunch of `double`s (think decimal points). Whenever you combine two different `type`s of values in R, it will bring them all up to one type. In this case `double`s. That is why your 20 looks like 20.00. Simple answer is you can't have both 20 and 4.42. Plus, why would you want to?